# List type casting error in dart when getting Map values as a List

Tags: flutter, dart, types, error-handling, casting

I'm getting the error below even when I set the type of the variable as List

[image]

Error persists in a dynamic List

[image]

Version info of flutter:

[image]

Comment: instead of image, you could share code

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code.

```dart
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> groupFiles = {'g1': 'abc', 'g2': 'xyz'};
  List<String> peopleNames = [];
  
  final groupFilesValues = groupFiles.values.toList().runtimeType;
  print(groupFilesValues); // List<dynamic>
  
  final values = groupFiles.values.map((v) => v.toString()).toList();
  peopleNames.addAll(values);
  
  print(values.runtimeType); // List<String>
  print(peopleNames); // [abc, xyz]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately I got the same error

Comment: Will that be possible for you to share an example of `groupFiles` and how it looks like? Also one thing, does this `groupFiles.values.map((v) => v.toString()).toList()` give **same error**? I mean as long as each values have `toString` method implemented, it should not at least produce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it

1. Created a variable called parsedJSON which holds the parsed Map with dynamic type
2. Created sexyfiedMap which is also a Map but with static types.
3. Used a loop to save the keys and values from the dynamic Map into the Map with static types and returned it

```dart
Future<Map<String,List<String>>> loadGroupsFile()async{
  Directory appDataFolder = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  File groupsFile = File(appDataFolder.path + "/groups/groups.json");
  Map<String,dynamic> parsedJSON;
  Map<String,List<String>> sexyfiedMap = {};
  try{
    String groupsJSON = await groupsFile.readAsString();
    //type cast in order to be able to store the values on the variables
    parsedJSON = jsonDecode(groupsJSON);
  }catch(err){
    parsedJSON = {};
  }
  for(String key in parsedJSON.keys){
    sexyfiedMap.addAll({
      key : [],
    });
  }
  return sexyfiedMap;
}
```